# How to do Sum Operation in SQl Pivot Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here i have a simple table Name Cust With CustName,PurshaseItem,Price.I wrote a Simple PIVOT query its Pivoting the data but i wana to show sum of the amot
Here i need Grand  total

**Pivot Query**

```
[![select custName,

       \[Shoes\] as Shoes,
       \[Colgate\] as Colgate,
       \[Cloths\] as Cloths

FROM
(select custName,Price,PurchaseItem FROM Cust
) AS PIVOTData

PIVOT(
sum(Price) FOR PurchaseItem 
IN (Shoes,Colgate,Cloths)
)AS PIVOTING][1]][1]


custname       Shoes    Colgate       GrandTotal
xyz           12         10           22
lmn            1          2            3
```

Comment: Add sample data and result expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
CREATE TABLE CUST (custName VARCHAR(10),
       price INT,
       PurchaseItem VARCHAR(10)
       )
       INSERT INTO CUST VALUES ('aaaa', 1,'Colgate')
       INSERT INTO CUST VALUES ('aaaa', 2,'Shoes')
       INSERT INTO CUST VALUES ('aaaa', 3,'Cloths')
       INSERT INTO CUST VALUES ('bbbb', 4,'Colgate')
       INSERT INTO CUST VALUES ('bbbb', 5,'Shoes')
       INSERT INTO CUST VALUES ('bbbb', 6,'Cloths')


select *
FROM
(select custName, SUM(Price)   AS Price ,
     CASE WHEN GROUPING(PurchaseItem)=1 THEN 'TOT_PRICE' ELSE PurchaseItem END AS PurchaseItem
  FROM Cust
  group by rollup(PurchaseItem), custName
) AS PIVOTData

PIVOT(sum(Price) FOR PurchaseItem IN (Shoes,Colgate,Cloths,TOT_PRICE)) AS PIVOTING
```

Output:

```
custName   Shoes       Colgate     Cloths      TOT_PRICE
---------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
aaaa       2           1           3           6
bbbb       5           4           6           15
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add this to your select

```
coalesce([Shoes], 0) + coalesce([Colgate], 0) + coalesce([Cloths], 0) as GranTotal
```

The `coalesce` is needed to avoid weird behaviours when one of the results is `null`.